# array name decaying to pointer in c - error compiling

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

In the code below, I get the following warning using the function `mraa_spi_write_buf()`.

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
>   [-Wint-conversion]  read_data[0] = mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, cmd, 2);

I thought that array names decay to pointers in c?

This is the function declaration for the function

`uint8_t * mraa_spi_write_buf (mraa_spi_context dev, uint8_t *data, int length).`

```
#include "mraa.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

uint8_t cmd[2] = {0xAA, 0xFF};
uint8_t read_data[2];

read_data[0] = mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, cmd, 2);

}
```

Comment: Are you assigning an array? Have a close look! What is the type of `read_data[0]`?

Comment: "I thought that array names decay to pointers in c?" - Not always. Arrays are not pointers. And it is not clear what you are trying; as-is, it makes no sense at all.

Comment: Well, *almost* always.  The exceptions are enumerated: "when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array" (C2011, 6.3.2.1/3).  But that's not related to the problem in your code..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the parameter, its the return value, the function returns a pointer, which you are then assigning to the integer variable `read_data[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that array names decay to pointers in c?

You can use the array name as a pointer to the first element of the array, but aside from this case, this is not true.

Your function returns int*, so you need to dereference to get the value:

```
uint8_t* recv; 
recv = mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, cmd, 2)
if( recv != NULL)
{
   read_data[0] = *(mraa_spi_write_buf(spi, cmd, 2));
}
else
{
  //Handle error
}
free(recv);
```

Edit: Thanks for the correction @JeremyP.

Comment: I found the [documentation here](https://iotdk.intel.com/docs/master/mraa/spi_8h.html#a794395b9eae7ed095c63beb76e8e6930). The pointer returned is to malloc'd storage that has to be freed by the caller, so your fragment, although fixing the immediate problem leaks the buffer.